# How can I instruct IntelliJ Idea to not include certatin dependencies (android)

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

My project layout is

```
/ServerModule
  /commonClasses

/AndroidClient
  /needsToIncludeSomeCommonClasses
```

but as soon as i want to compile and build my `AndroidClient IntelliJ` adds the server `libs` to the compile `classpath` of my android project and I get a `UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION` because of multiple classes that are present in android and normal java.

My question is how can i set up my project without duplicating the server code?

It seems to be a problem with the android-plugin.

It includes all the `serverside libs in the build`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

I need to make a new module with common classes only and link this with the other two modules. Not very pretty but it works

Comment: In fact the longer i work like this, it seems actually quite pretty ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I would ask IntelliJ support, http://www.jetbrains.com/support/idea/index.html they are usually very responsive or ask their Community Support Forum. http://www.jetbrains.com/devnet/

Comment: I sent them a sample project.